# Ubuntu stuck on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

[stuck ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWfJ.png)

Here, ubuntu is getting stuck with mouse not moving and nothing else is loading.
look at the image for better understanding.
I've installed latest version of Ubuntu LTS 22.04 using an iso file, selected 2nd generation while creating this VM